# Tasks Vs. Tâches - Outlook 2003

Tags: language, microsoft-outlook-2003, import, pst, tasks

I am working in a french IT environment and I have a lawyer here that his Outlook and Windows XP SP3 is in french. I changed his old laptop (English) for a new one (French).

In Outlook 2003 on his old laptop, he had the Tasks menu and all of his tasks were sync'ed with his iPhone. Now since it's in french, Tasks has been changed for "Tâches" and it's now sync'ing anymore...

I tried to export all of his tasks in a .PST file and then tried to delete Tasks and import the data in the .pst file in Tâche. Right now, I just can get rid of Tasks and also can't import anything in "Tâches" without having another "Tasks2" created...

I've been looking on the web and some MS forum without any luck. I seem to be the only one on earth having this issue...

Any takers?

Comment: You may wanna ask on serverfault also...

Comment: Not a bad idea... I thought about posting it on SF but this maybe fixed on client side. I had the same issue with Calandar and Calendrier but I can't fix it with Tasks...

Comment: I'm  guessing someone there has dealt with it before, is the reason.  I'm willing to bet there is a Quebecois sys admin that has been through it.

Comment: I'm a sys admin... it's just that I don't deal a lot with that! And quebec is 'da place to be! So many hot chicaz!

Comment: Might be a dumb question: Can't you rename the folder to Tasks?

Comment: I can't... I've been trying in so many ways to do this but no luck. I also checked the registry but nothing in there. And this is not a dumb question! There's none!